# How to get properties of the class that a generic list uses

Tags: c#, wpf

Didn't know a good title for this but anyway. I am currently making a program in WPF, a basic shop program/interface.I have a banjo class with proprieties such as the banjo name, banjoID, banjo state(out,instock). I have another class called cStock which has a static member list that stores all the banjos, so `static List<cBanjo> banjoList = new List<cBanjo>();`

Ok so on my WPF program, I have a listBox, that is meant to show the banjo names one by one. I can add banjo/create banjos aswell, So if I create two banjos, their names will be "Banjo1" and "Banjo2", I want it to show their names only, nothing else. The problem is I have no idea how to do it.

I have set the itemsource of the listBox, to the banjo list, like this `listBox_BanjoList.ItemsSource = cStock.BanjoList`, but what I really want is something along the lines of `listBox_BanjoList.ItemsSource = cStock.BanjoList.banjoName`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify an [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) for your [`ListView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx), e.g. something like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BanjoList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding banjoName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: The DisplayMemberBinding property works great too for this kind of  bindings. `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BanjoList}" DisplayMemberBinding=banjName"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You chould simply do..

```
listBox_BanjoList.ItemsSource = cStock.BanjoList.Select(banjo => new string(banjo.banjoName.ToCharArray()));
```

but, the preferred method is what user `poke` indicated. With WPF, you should be using MVVM, which can allow you to bind your `ListBox` to a `List` property.

Example ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Banjo> _banjoList;
    public ObservableCollection<Banjo> BanjoList
    {
        get { return _banjoList; }
        set
        {
            _banjoList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BanjoList");
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        // populate list
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BanjoList}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding BanjoName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well am pretty new to WPF overall,so I dont know what MVVM or data templates are, so I guess I got a lot to learn :)

Comment: If you use the first approach I showed you, it should work. It's simply just taking your initial list and creating a new list w/ only BanjoName.